# Jquery issue on mobile happening on one page and not another

Tags: jquery, html

I have two different pages I am working with.  One of them doesn't have the issue and the other one does.  The problem is I have span tags that I have a class on which I use to detect on changes and perform an action.  For example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("click",".test",function(){
        $(this).html("changed");
    });     
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Invoice Management</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="Scripts/controlscript.js"></script>
</head>
<span class="test" style="background-color:red;">Hello</span>
```

So on click of the span tag that has test class should change the text to changed.  This works perfectly fine on my computer but when I try it on my mobile device it doesn't do anything.  The stranger issue is that I have another page that I used the same method for links and it works perfectly fine.  Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: add `$(document).ready(function() {` script at the end of `<head>` tag as you are adding jquery lib in head but adding script before head.

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar he has shown his code. not as it is, i think. Because he can not execute it without script tag.

Comment: @PHJCJO, yeah may be your right but I just thought of if that is the case.

Comment: @user541597 where is your function call? is it in Scripts/controlscript.js?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the structure.  If I change my span tags to a tags it works fine.

Comment: @user541597 You can not say that while the above shown structure is entirely wrong. you can separate the js and HTML in the question to get the better answer, or if it is the way your code is, try the given solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.  Looks like a bug with mobile browsers.  Adding cursor:pointer; to the span class works.  Here is a link.  http://www.shdon.com/blog/2013/06/07/why-your-click-events-don-t-work-on-mobile-safari

Comment: better you modify the question as a well formatted one.

Answer (score 0):

First the code you posted is not well structured. to use any js library functions , first you need to load that js library before using any functions defined in that library.

ex :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> ----> keep this line first


$(document).ready(function() {}); -----> next to the above line
```

Comment: script works correctly if I change my tags to a tags instead of span.

Comment: if I change this line to an a tag instead of a span it works. <span class="test" style="background-color:red;">Hello</span>